# How can I use plugins with vuechart.js v5.2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I have a Linear chart which works perfectly fine but I would like there to be some spacing between the legend to improve it visually.

As far as I know, this can be done in chartjs with plugins, like shown in this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87rnMzENg3U&t=269s

Now, since I am using vuechartJS as a wrapper for chartJS I'd like to know how I can pass a custom plugin to achieve the desired output.

Does someone know how I can do that? What I've seen is that people use their plugin in the options object but I haven't been able to make it work yet.

The basic structure for my options object is this (this is the simplified version, each key has it's configuration in the actual code) and the name of my plugin is legendMarginPlugin

```
{
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  title: {},
  elements: {},
  scales: {},
  plugins: {
    legend: {},
    tooltip: {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63244800/2358409